# Add hint bulb for users in eclipse rcp procuct

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on eclipse RCP product. I want to know how to add hints to users. I mean when they open our tool for the first time, I want to add some hints to click here and there (kind of a walk-through of the tool). Not just light bulb hint (which we see in eclipse), some other different types of arrows as well. My requirement can be best illustrated with the interactive tutorial of criminal case game in facebook. Please check this image with hints: http://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/673844-criminal-case-browser-screenshot-first-crime-scene-a-tutorial.jpg. When the user accesses the game for the first time, they have a very nice walk through. Can this be done in eclipse? May be not this much fancier, but at least basic version with an arrow to indicate user to click the button, and then the next button, and so on. Please let me know if any of you have idea on this. It would be of great help. Please point me to any example if it is available online.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `popup` to achieve this. Each hint is an SWT `popup` and place it in the right location.